# Facebook: Issue getting graph api response of my wall feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been messing around with the Graph API explorer. When I get an access code and make the query something like:

```
/me/feed?access_token=[some access token]&until=[day after my birthday]
```

I get an empty response array...no error, just empty

This same syntax is used with a day displaying more than just my birthday wall feed and it works. It appears as if facebook is taking issue with me trying to access the posts on my wall during my birthday.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks so much

Comment: try this : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Funtil%3D2012-04-02

Comment: just specify 'since' attribute and try again..